# Calling a function from a function pointer in Delphi

Tags: multithreading, delphi, callback, delphi-2010

I'm trying to build a generic worker thread in Delphi, one that I can pass a function/procedure (doesn't matter) as an argument and let it execute.

My guess is to add a field in the `TThread` class and call it from `TThread.Execute`.

So the code outside the thread is gonna be:

```
  MyThread := TWorkerThread.Create(True);
  Mythread.CallBackF := @Foo;
  try
    MyThread.Resume;
  except
    MyThread.Free;
  end;
```

How do I keep a reference of  `@foo` in the `TWorkerThread` and call it from inside `Execute`?

Comment: The above code is very, very bad. You free the thread immediately after creating it. (Yes, the thread runs in... a separate thread. Maybe you want a `WaitFor`?)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andreas, I'll edit it. I don't have much experience with threads in delphi tbh.

Comment: And btw, I don't want to wait for the thread. Is that what `WaitFor` does? I'm not not expecting any decision making return, just a networking routines that need up to 500 Milliseconds.

Comment: @Ed.C: Yes, WaitFor will not return until the thread is complete. You probably do not want this. Maybe `FreeOnTerminate` will do it?

Comment: If the only intended use of your thread class is for it to have a parameter assigned and then run, then don't bother allowing it to be created any other way. The object *requires* a callback pointer, so make that be a parameter to the constructor. And it's *never* supposed to sit around suspended, so *don't* make that a parameter. You can then just create the thread and forget it: `TWorkerThread.Create(Foo)`. In the constructor, call `inherited Create(False)`, set `CallBackF`, and set `FreeOnTerminate := True`.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, TThread destructor waits for thread completion with message pumping, so this code is correct (except it doesn't perform async execution, if that's what you're after).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [QueueUserWorkItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684957(VS.85).aspx) function.

It executes arbitrary function in a thread, without requiring you to create one.
Just don't forget to switch IsMultithreaded global variable to True.

Comment: "... without *the application programmer* requiring to create one", I suppose?

Comment: Yep. (stackoverflow doesn't allow short comments, so I write this...)

Comment: CreateThread seems more appropriate since according to msdn QueueUserWorkItem is meant for Thread Pools

Comment: `QueueUserWorkItem` looks really neat! I can even pass arguments with that!

Comment: @Remko, *uses* thread pool. That's why this function is cool. You can shedule work item without worrying about threads, pools, sync issues... Being front-end of built-in thread pool - it's description of internal implementation, that's all. Which means that you must play fair (for example, don't forget about WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION). It's not a sign "don't use this function!".

Answer (score 6):

Also, a good start into using generic threads would be [AsyncCalls](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=100) or [Omni Thread Library](http://otl.17slon.com/index.htm).

Comment: Thank you for your reply @skamradt. They really look nice libraries. I might keep them in mind for any bigger projects, but for now I'm going for the constructor with argument method. It's just a small app really, I'm already finished - just going through optimizations now. :)

Answer (score 5):

I do not pretend to be an expert on threading, but I think this will do it:

```
interface

    type
      TProcRef = reference to procedure;
      TWorkerThread = class(TThread)
      public
        proc: TProcRef;
        procedure Execute; override;
        class procedure RunInThread(AProc: TProcRef);
      end;

implementation

procedure TWorkerThread.Execute;
begin
  inherited;
  proc;
end;

class procedure TWorkerThread.RunInThread(AProc: TProcRef);
begin
  with TWorkerThread.Create(true) do
  begin
    FreeOnTerminate := true;
    proc := AProc;
    Resume;
  end;
end;
```

Then, if you got any procedure, like

```
procedure P;
begin
  while true do
  begin
    sleep(1000);
    beep;
  end;
end;
```

you can just do

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TWorkerThread.RunInThread(P);
end;
```

You can even do

```
TWorkerThread.RunInThread(procedure begin while true do begin sleep(1000); beep; end; end);
```

Comment: +1 @Andreas Rejbrand, nice Code, is it posible to add parameter on such procedure? like procedure P(AValue:String; AValue:Integer);?

Comment: Ed, if you have to put `@` in front of a procedure name, that's usually an indication that the procedure-pointer type and the procedure you're trying to pass to it do not match. Make sure the signatures match exactly; do not try to pass a function where a procedure is expected or vice versa. @XBasic, yes, you can add whatever parameters you want. Just make sure you add them to the type declaration, too: `TProcRef = reference to procedure(AValue: string; AValue2: Integer)`

Comment: Is there a difference between `TProcRef = reference to procedure` and `TProcRef = procedure`, except that the former does not compile with earlier versions?